# Nested template parameters for functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming

```
template <typename T> class foo2 {
};
```

Sample 1

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class foo2>
foo2<T> func2(){
}
```

Sample 2

```
template <template <typename T> class foo2>
foo2<T> func2(){
}
```

I  have a template class and I would like to write a function that accepts only that class (with any of it's templates of course)
why does sample 1 works and 2 does not?

Edit:

Please provide an explanation of how the matching happens? Clearly the function in sample 1 takes two template parameters without any default values, however in the call in the main only one parameter is provided.

Edit2:
 I want another  func2 overload for the templated foo2 class, I already have defined in my code.

```
template <typename T>
T func2(){
}
```

Comment: I think you want `template <typename T> void func2(foo2<T>) { }`.

Comment: That is correct but in the context of my project I have already this template and I want an overload for the templated foo2 class. I will add this detail to the post. Thanks!

Comment: The inner typename does not formally introduce the type placeholder. This is just the way the syntax works AFAIA.

Comment: and how does the matching happen?

Comment: @RichardHodges The inner typename can be used like this: 
`template <template <typename T, T> class>`.

Answer (score 4):

Template template parameters define a template name in the body of the function. You have to provide the parameter to instantiate them. This means that the `T` in

```
template <template <typename T> class foo2> void func2(foo2<T>);
```

is not visible elsewhere; only the template name `foo2` is.

Your first sample,

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class foo2> void func2(foo2<T>);
```

works because the T is a top-level template type parameter, which is

1. visible to the function body, and
2. deduced from the function argument.

However, this use case is more easily written with a simple template type parameter and direct use of the class `foo2`:

```
template <typename T> void func2(foo2<T>);
```

See, for example, [template parameters and template arguments](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) on cppreference for details

---

Note, the question was edited after I wrote the above, and the type is no longer used as a function argument. The point about type deduction no longer applies, but the rest of the answer stands.